# How to stop turtle from drawing even with pen up?

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics

I am using the turtle module in python. the problem is that whenever I have the turtle move i will draw even if the pen is up. for example if I run this program:

```
import turtle

turtle.penup
turtle.goto(0,50)
```

the turtle will still draw a line when it moves  to (0,50)
why is this and how can it be prevented?

Answer (score 10):

It looks like you're not actually calling turtle.penup. Try this:

```
import turtle

turtle.penup()
turtle.goto(0,50)
```

Answer (score 4):

You have a typo, you aren't calling the penup method:

```
import turtle

turtle.penup() #This needs to be a method call
turtle.goto(0,50)
```

Answer (score 1):

import turtle

`turtle.up()
turtle.goto(0,50)
turtle.down()`

if you don't put the pen down it will keep on drawing in invisible condition.

Answer (score 1):

This question is super old and definitely has already been answered, but I'll leave this explanation here for future people

"penup" is a method in Python, aka function in other languages. This means that when you want to use it you have it include some parenthesis just so that your code knows what is supposed to be happening

```
import turtle

turtle.penup()
turtle.goto(0,50)
```

When you don't include the parenthesis, the code thinks you are talking about a variable, and looks for one called "penup", but there is no variable of that name, so Python throws its hands up and crashes

Answer (score 0):

you called penup without (). with

```
turtle.penup()
```

this will work.

Others here said that, but implicitly. trying to ensure it is clear where the typo is.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably try,

```
turtle.penup()
```

Comment: If the intent was to convey that they need to add `()` after penup to turn it into a function call that should be stated in an explanation that goes with the code. This is also a seven year old question with existing answers that already covered that aspect of the question.

Answer (score -3):

no it should be something like this:

```
turtle.up()         # This a method call
turtle.goto(0,50)   # Part of the method call
```