# Python turtle screen

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

How can I set the turtle to a part of the screen so that it starts there.

```
import turtle
import random

wn = turtle.Screen() #sets the screen
wn.screensize(1000,1000)
ad = turtle.Turtle() #names the turtle
ad.shape("circle") #changes turtles or "ad's" shape
ad.speed(98989898989898989898989898989898989898)
r = 100 #CHANGES THE SIZE OF THE WRITING

x_pos = 1000 - r*2
y_pos = 1000 - r 
ad.penup()

ad.setx(-x_pos)
ad.sety(y_pos)
ad.pendown()
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: "How can I set the turtle to a part of the screen so that it starts there"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to stop turtle from drawing even with pen up?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15602192/how-to-stop-turtle-from-drawing-even-with-pen-up)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you `goto` a pair of screen coordinates, keeping in mind that the origin is at (0, 0) at the center of the screen.

```
ad = turtle.Turtle()
ad.penup()
ad.goto(200, 200)
ad.pendown()

# then start drawing:
ad.forward(100)
```

Comment: I want the turtle to go to (900, -900) and then start drawing. But it just disappears.

Comment: Yes, unless your screen is ginormous, that location must be outside of the visible canvas. Try with 90, -90 to see it working first.

Answer (score 1):

> I want the turtle to go to (900, -900) and then start drawing. But it
>   just disappears.

When you write:

```
wn.screensize(1000,1000)
```

you are sizing the window with a visible coordinate system that goes from roughly `(-499, -499)` in the lower left to `(500, 500)` in the upper right.  (Actually, we may lose a dozen or more bits from the upper right coordinates due to borders and other "chrome".)  So you can see why your `(900, -900)` position is out of view.

The coordinate system can be adjusted to better match your needs but it's probably worthwhile learning the default coordinate system first.  Your example reworked:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

WIDTH, HEIGHT = 1000, 1000

wn = Screen()  # sets the screen
wn.setup(WIDTH, HEIGHT)

ad = Turtle()  # names the turtle
ad.shape('circle')  # changes turtle's or "ad's" shape
ad.speed('fastest')

r = 100
x_pos = r * 2 - WIDTH / 2
y_pos = HEIGHT / 2 - r

ad.penup()

ad.setposition(x_pos, y_pos)

ad.pendown()

wn.mainloop()
```

Comment: this isn't working when I define functions for keyboard input. wn.onkey(lambda: a(), "a")

Comment: @jercai, that comment has nothing to do with your original question so isn't appropriate here.  However, have you done `wn.listen()`, just once, in your code to allow your window to respond to keyboard events?  Also, you need to click on the window to make it responsive before typing.